# How to change the static IP address of an adaptor in Ubuntu using a script?

Tags: networking, 22.04, network-manager, internet, ethernet

In Ubuntu 22.04 I am trying to change the static IP address of a single network interface **without changing anything else**. This interface is an ethernet-to-USB converter connected to local ethernet devices (and not used to connect to the internet). I found the following script

```
#!/bin/bash

# Network interface name
INTERFACE="enx00e04c680202"

# Static IP address configuration
IP_ADDRESS="192.168.200.99"
NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
GATEWAY="192.168.200.220"
DNS_SERVER="8.8.8.8"

# Backup existing network configuration file
sudo cp /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml.bak

# Create or modify the Netplan configuration file
sudo tee /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml > /dev/null <<EOF
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    $INTERFACE:
      addresses: [$IP_ADDRESS/24]
      gateway4: $GATEWAY
EOF

# Apply the new network configuration
sudo netplan apply
```

which does change the static IP address of the interface `enx00e04c680202`, but it somehow affects other configurations so I was not able to connect to the internet anymore!

The ifconfig looks like that

```
enp84s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 7c:57:58:80:1c:61  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0x54000000-540fffff  

enx00e04c680202: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.200.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.200.255
        ether 00:e0:4c:68:02:02  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 281  bytes 12926 (12.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 41  bytes 5083 (5.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enxa0cec8c97ebc: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether a0:ce:c8:c9:7e:bc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1054  bytes 131881 (131.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1054  bytes 131881 (131.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp0s20f3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.11  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 2a01:cb15:d7:c00:b8e9:ab1c:e07e:a0af  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2a01:cb15:d7:c00:1be3:f260:49cf:f265  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::83c9:9667:953e:6ca1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 3c:e9:f7:a7:1c:0f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 32356  bytes 40427564 (40.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 32  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 19027  bytes 3230853 (3.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I see the following interfaces:

- `enp84s0`: No idea what this is
- `enx00e04c680202`: The interface who's IP address I try to change using a simple command line command
- `enxa0cec8c97ebc`: Probably the name of a disconnected USB-to-ethernet interface
- `wlp0s20f3`: Most likely the wireless interface that connects the computer to internet over WLAN

Of course I want to stay connected to the internet, and that command I am looking for should ONLY change the address `192.168.200.100` for the interface `enx00e04c680202`.

So how can I fix this script, or maybe there is a more simpler command to do that? (It has to be a command line command as I might need to change the static IP address very often ...)

I tried the solution suggested by running

```
sudo /sbin/ip addr add 192.168.200.99/24 dev enx00e04c680202
```

but in `ifconfig` the old IP address is still shown for that interface. I also tried

```
sudo /sbin/ip link set dev enx00e04c680202 down
sudo /sbin/ip addr add 192.168.200.99/24 dev enx00e04c680202
sudo /sbin/ip link set dev enx00e04c680202 up
```

but it still does not seem to change the interface. Finally I tried

```
sudo systemctl restart networking
```

which .gives an error

```
Failed to restart networking.service: Unit networking.service not found.
```

Comment: sudo /sbin/ip addr add 192.168.200.100/24 dev enx00e04c680202

Comment: @petep  That command does not seem to work. In `ifconfig` I still see the old static address ...

Answer (score 0):

For me the following script does exactly what I need:

```
#!/bin/bash
INTERFACE=enx00e04c680202
sudo ifconfig $INTERFACE down
sudo ifconfig $INTERFACE $1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

and then I call this script like

```
./set_network_address.sh 192.168.200.99
```